# Find matching values in javascript objects

Tags: javascript

```js
let flightInfo = {
userInputFlightNumber: 'KL856',
};

const xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest;
const url2 = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/11uvvr';


xhr2.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xhr2.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
   let converTimetableToObject = JSON.parse(xhr2.response);
    console.log(converTimetableToObject);

          let resultArray = converTimetableToObject.response.flight.filter(function () {
              return (converTimetableToObject.response.flight.iata_number == flightInfo.userInputFlightNumber);
          });


console.log(resultArray);
console.log(flightInfo.userInputFlightNumber);
console.log(converTimetableToObject);


     }
   }
xhr2.open('GET', url2);
xhr2.send();
```

My variable **converTimetableToObject** holds multiple objects. For example:

```
response: [
{
flight: {
number: "8421",
iata_number: "AF8421",
icao_number: "AFR8421"
departure_time: 8:00,
},
flight: {
number: "856",
iata_number: "KL856",
icao_number: "KLM856"
departure_time: 10:00,
}
flight: {
number: "5925",
iata_number: "KE5925",
icao_number: "KAL5925"
departure_time: 12:00,
},
flight: {
number: "856",
iata_number: "KL856",
icao_number: "KLM856"
departure_time: 15:30,
}
```

Property **flightInfo.userInputFlightNumber** holds the user input which is also an iata_number. How can I filter all matching flight numbers?

I tried the filter method, but it keeps returning an empty array.

```
 xhr2.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if (xhr2.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
 let converTimetableToObject = JSON.parse(xhr2.response);
 let resultArray = converTimetableToObject.response.filter(function () 
 {return (converTimetableToObject.response.flight.iata_number == 
 flightInfo.userInputFlightNumber); });    }   }
```

My goal is to match the iatacodes and display the departure time of the matching values.

Comment: The filter should work assuming `userInputFlightNumber` has a valid value. Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces your problem

Comment: Thanks! I added a runable example. The resultArray stays empty

Answer (score 0):

If you look at how [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works, it's not what you expect. Inside filter you should have a function and as a parameter to the function you give the array element. So something like this. You can also see how it works yourself, by adding the parameter to the callback and console.logging the parameter to see what the element currently is.

`arr.filter(e => return e.flight.iata_number === flightInfo.userInputFlightNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your array is incorrect because it have duplicate property name 'flight'
It should be like

```
 var obj='{"response":{"flight": [{ "number": "8421", "iata_number": "AF8421", "icao_number": "AFR8421", "departure_time": "8: 00" }, { "number": "856", "iata_number": "KL856", "icao_number": "KLM856", "departure_time": "10: 00" }, { "number": "5925", "iata_number": "KE5925", "icao_number": "KAL5925", "departure_time": "12: 00" }, { "number": "856", "iata_number": "KL856", "icao_number": "KLM856", "departure_time": "15: 30" }     ]   } }';
```

Then you can apply filter as

```
var arr=converTimetableToObject.response.flight;

var filtered=arr.filter(el=> el.iata_number===flightInfo.userInputFlightNumber);
```

Comment: Still not what I meant, like this: `var filtered = arr.filter(el => el.iata_number === flightInfo.userInputFlightNumber);`

Comment: Fixed the json file and the array is correct. The array stays empty

Comment: I made some changes to it with your changed JSON and suggestion from @Darren and it's working now, i created fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ydd5Lctz/7/

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one your JSON is completely invalid.

You should open your JSON with either an array or object.
**ALL** items in the file must be quoted with double quotes.
Duplicate keys are also illegal, unless under another object or array: all your "flight" : {} keys won't work, but the various keys inside are fine, since they're referenced through different objects. (So your converTimetableToObject.response.flight.iata_number matches EVERY entry.)
Commas belong at the end of every object EXCEPT the last within individual objects or arrays. (You don't have one after your icao numbers, but you do after your departure times.)

This is what your JSON should look like:

```
{
"response": {
    "flight": [{
            "number": "8421",
            "iata_number": "AF8421",
            "icao_number": "AFR8421",
            "departure_time": "8: 00"
        },
        {
            "number": "856",
            "iata_number": "KL856",
            "icao_number": "KLM856",
            "departure_time": "10: 00"
        },
        {
            "number": "5925",
            "iata_number": "KE5925",
            "icao_number": "KAL5925",
            "departure_time": "12: 00"
        },
        {
            "number": "856",
            "iata_number": "KL856",
            "icao_number": "KLM856",
            "departure_time": "15: 30"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

You'll then have to process the flight array through a for loop to retrieve all the iata_numbers.

Something like this:

```
xhr2.onreadystatechange = function(){
  let resultArray = [];
  let flight = converTimetableToObject.response.flight;
  let lastFlight = flight.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < lastFlight; i++) {
    if (flight[i].iata_number == flightInfo.userInputFlightNumber) {
      resultArray.push(flight[i].iata_number) // push adds a new item to an existing array
    }
  }
  // do something with resultArray
}
```

**Edit:** I suppose you can do something with `filter`, but that function is new to me, so follow the examples of the others.